# How to get  Windows 8 Release Preview Aero lite Theme in Windows7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8-preview, themes, aero

So, I find myself liking the default wpf theme for the aerolite visual style in Windows 8 RP

After a little digging, I found a few files called

- PresentationFramework.Aero2.ni.dll.

I was wondering if there was a way to get these in Windows 7 in such a way that by applying a Windows visual style named "aerolite.msstyles" would make wpf use the aero2 theme (Basically just like in Windows 8 RP).

Comment: You understand this theme is being removed from Windows 8 RTM right?

Comment: The fact of the matter is, I have gotten the Windows 8 RTM trial, and the visual style actually is still there, and it is what gets used for the high-contrast windows 8 themes, since the classic theme is removed. So no, it's not being removed from the rtm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [theme pack](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Vista-Transformation-Pack.shtml)?

Comment: Actually, what I want is for the theme to be built in to the GAC (So that, say, Visual Studio 2010 will use the theme when I switch visual styles.).